# array function C++

Tags: c++, arrays, function

The question can be found [here](http://venus.cs.qc.cuny.edu/~waxman/211/eqivalent%20arrays.pdf).

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

bool equivalent(int a[], int b[], int n)
{
    int i=0, j=0, count =0;
    while (a[i]!=b[j])
    {
        count++;
        j++;
    }

    for(int i=0; i<=n; i++)
        if(a[i]%n==b[i+count]%n) return true;
        else return false;
}


int main()
{
    int a[]={1,2,3,4,5};
    int b[]={1,4,5,3,2};
    cout<< equivalent(a,b,5)<<endl;

    return 0;
}
```

When I run my code, it outputs 1 which is true. But from the code above, it should output false.

where did I do wrong?

Comment: When??? Probably when you wrote it.

Comment: sorry i meant "what"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
bool equivalent(int a[], int b[], int n) {
    int i=0, j=0, count=0;
    // This condition fails immediately because the values are equal
    while (a[i] != b[j]) {
        // For this reason neither count nor j are incremented
        count++;
        j++;
    }

    for (int i=0; i<=n; i++)
        // This condition succeeds immediately because these values are equal
        if (a[i] % n == b[i+count] % n)
            // And true is returned.
            return true;
        else
            return false;
}
```

Please note there are also several other problems in the code. The first loop doesn't have a safe end condition, the second loop has off-by-one end condition, …

Comment: I am not sure if I understand your explanation. Could you explain it simply?

Comment: Add many `cout` outputs to your `equivalent` function to see what's in individual variables when the code executes. You will see precisely why individual conditions pass or fail.